# Fluent WPF API for inherited properties

Tags: c#, wpf, fluent, fluent-interface

Occasionally I'll have some WPF C# code that I'd like to write in a "fluent" manner.

For example, I might want to setup a `Window` containing a `ScrollViewer`:

```
new Window()
    .SetContent(
        new ScrollViewer()
            .SetContent(
                ...))
```

To achieve this sort of API, I've been using extension methods such as these:

```
static class FluentScrollViewer
{
    public static ScrollViewer SetContent(this ScrollViewer obj, object val)
    { obj.Content = val; return obj; }
}

static class FluentWindow
{
    public static Window SetContent(this Window obj, object val)
    { obj.Content = val; return obj; }
}
```

Now, `Window` and `ScrollViewer` both inherit the `Content` property from `ContentControl`. Yet, I've had to define the `SetContent` extension methods for each class separately.

If I try to do something like this instead:

```
static class FluentContentControl
{
    public static ContentControl SetContent(this ContentControl obj, object val)
    { obj.Content = val; return obj; }
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
new Window().SetContent(...)
```

the `SetContent` method doesn't return a `Window` of course.

Is there way to define `SetContent` over `ContentControl` and have it do the "right thing" so as to avoid defining lots of individually speciallized methods which are similar except for the type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluent interfaces and inheritance in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278781/fluent-interfaces-and-inheritance-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public static TControl SetContent<TControl>(this TControl obj, object val)
where TControl : ContentControl
{ 
    obj.Content = val; 
    return obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much gain in this when you are creating new controls as you could also use [initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
new Window() {
    Content = new ScrollViewer() { Content = ... }
};
```

Comment: +1 Initializers are much more readable than a long chain of fluent calls.

Comment: Initializers don't help to set properties on already existing objects however.

Comment: @dharmatech: As i said, this only applies to creating new controls. My answer is just an addition for this special case as Piotr already answered how to make the method generic.