# Nested Fluent Interface With PHP

Tags: php, oop

how i can create class with this call syntax

```
oop->open(file)->select_row(3)->update('this is row3')->save();
```

an other question 
if i have class and i wont make plugin for it , every plugin in each php file separate...  my Ex.

```
class Foo { 
    function foo1() { 
        print 'foo foo';
    }
}

function plugin_foo(){
   print 'this from plugin_foo';
}

$foo = new Foo; 
print $foo->foo1()->plugin_foo()

oop->open(file)->select_row(3)->update('this is row3')->save();
```

an other question 
if i have class and i wont make plugin for it , every plugin in each php file separate...  my Ex.

```
class Foo { 
    function foo1() { 
        print 'foo foo';
    }
}

function plugin_foo(){
   print 'this from plugin_foo';
}

$foo = new Foo; 
print $foo->foo1()->plugin_foo()
```

Comment: You can `return $this` in the functions you want to chain.

Comment: Just return`$this` in every method. This is called fluent interface

Comment: It is! You just have to make sure that the methods a `public` (and variables if you chain those)

Comment: answer in this post for c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790621/nested-fluent-interface

Answer (score 1):

It is called method chaining. By returning the instance of the itself, it can chain calls.

```
class Foobar
{ 
   function foo()
   {
      echo 'hi';

      return $this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the object of that same class in every methods.